# struct pack error: integer out of range for 'L' format code

Tags: python

I'm trying to transfer `int` data into ip address, for IPV6 and IPv4

```
def int2ip(i):
    if i > sys.maxint * 2 - 1: # ipv6
        socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, struct.pack('!L', i))
    socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET, struct.pack('!I', i)) # ipv4
```

But for a IPv6 address `240e:800::`, it's int represent is `47925062263553288224699872696711774208`, but while passing the int value to `int2ip`, throw the following error:

```
struct.error: integer out of range for 'L' format code
```

but the int value is really a `long` type:

```
>>> print(type(47925062263553288224699872696711774208)
<type 'long'>
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put a 128bit number into 32bit ('L' format code).

Python 3 has a library to manage ip addresses (4 & 6): https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html.
For python2 there is a backport: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress